# How to make auto hide in Visual Studio faster?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

For example, if I set the Solution Explorer to auto hide, it takes a second for it to animate away. I would prefer it to be instant. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Tools->Options->Environment->General`, you can disable `Animate environment tools`. This should do the trick.

Comment: This option is no longer available under this location for Visual Studio 2010. However, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't have this animation by default. It sometimes still keeps the solution explorer up for way too long before auto hiding it.